# Why was this question put on hold?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, on-hold

I am trying to better understand why this [Writing application for Windows Mobile 6.1 options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426471/writing-application-for-windows-mobile-6-1-options/17426644#17426644) was put on hold for being opinion based.

Note: It was not my question, but I provided an answer.

In my opinion, the question was not opinion based.  It asked what coding languages can be used to write for Mobile 6.1 or 6.5.  Although my answer received no negative feedback, the answer that I provided answered this question factually because I believed that the question was asking for a factual answer.  The person asking the question also stated that they were looking for a language such as Java or C++ and as Visual C++ was an option for this type of application development, I highlighted this fact.

As per http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/opinion it does not seem to constitute an opinion.  I can see it being opinion based if the question was something like "Which is easier for Mobile 6.1?"

**This is just what I make of the situation, as I said, I would like to understand the reasoning behind this and if I am wrong, the reason why. Perhaps citing another reason for closure would have been better?**

Comment: How is that *not* a shopping recommendation? *What can I use to write application* and *Where can I start and what are my options?*

Comment: I'd probably have voted to close as Too Broad, rather than Opinion Based, myself.

Comment: It's not a shopping recommendation because it's asking about coding languages, not software that is going to be purchased.  Certainly the question could be made more clear, but the context is about coding languages.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien - you're taking the "shopping" part literaly.  A shopping question is any question asking for recommendations, or "shopping" for suggestions.

Comment: @Patrick, we use "shopping" in a broader sense here, e.g. "shopping for ideas" or "shopping for code".

Comment: @Wooble Yeah, I probably should have closed as **Off topic** -> "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  The two you mentioned are pretty close to the same meaning, but I think that one would have been the best.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the shopping request terminology.

Additionally, why is my question being downvoted now?

Comment: @PatrickSebastien I have no idea, given GrigoriP's terrible question your answer was as good an answer as the OP could expect.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta and particularly the section on voting.

Comment: @LBT Doesn't that make most legitimate questions a shopping question? A legitimate "How do I do x" question can be invalidated with a rewording of "What do you recommend to do x".

Comment: @user2461391 It depends if they're looking for a library/tool/product or if they're looking for a solution to a problem (which may well include a library/tool/product, but they'll probably know in advance which one it is)

Comment: @user2461391 No, asking for a recommendation on *what to do* is fine. Asking us to recommend a library, tool, or other resource (books, tutorials, etc.) is off-topic.

Comment: @user2461391, "how do I do X" without research effort or a code sample cannot be reliably answered either, and should be closed. In that sense, it's akin to "what do you recommend to do X" if the questioner does not provide enough context, only his/her requirements.

Comment: @Bart I edited the question to specifically be related to asking why the question was put on hold for the cited reason of being opinion based.  Perhaps this makes this question a better fit for the voting scheme on meta.

Comment: For the record, "opinion based" is still correct, in that this question is asking for an opinion, "which language is best for doing X" and there really is no objective answer to that question, it's just all personal opinions.  Several others apply, and a few may well be a bit more focused onto this problem, but the existing reason wasn't *wrong*.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien You have one downvote on meta, not really an indication of a problem.  In fact, you only have two votes and yet comments from quite a number of people, meaning those that are reading the question aren't really sure how to vote and have abstained.

Comment: @Servy thank you for helping me to understand this by adding context.  I am generally new to SO and meta and am still trying to hone my understanding in order to contribute in better manners.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien I don't see why you'd need to know anything about meta to understand that.  You have 2 votes and yet 10 distinct users have *commented*, let alone the other 26 people who viewed the page.  Clearly at least 8 of the people who commented haven't voted (yet).

Comment: @Servy I'm... sorry? I'm trying to be constructive here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed it to the best close reason.

> Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

There are two others that are close to the right meaning on the first page of the close dialog, **too broad** and **primarily opinion-based**, but I think the off-topic reason above is tailored specifically for this kind of question.